# Build a dynamic Query using filter criteria

Tags: apex

Here is what i am trying to build.

I have set of parameters which the user would select to build the SOSL query

[image]

Also there is a criteria field (like in Workflows) where you enter (1 AND 2) OR 4

Here i am building query based on the criteria checked.

I am building the criteria using the code below. I have defined each condition in a map and replacing the numbers with the condition.

eg. 1 => name='Cisco', 2 => Email_domain__c = 'cisco.com', 3=> 'Tx', 4=> 'United states'

```
//Method to parse the criteria to get where condition
public static String parseCriteria(String str, Map<Integer, String> filtermap)
{
    String output = str;
    for(Integer i = 1; i <= filterMap.size(); i++){
        System.debug(i);
                if(output.contains(String.valueOf(i))){
                    output = output.replace(String.valueOf(i),filterMap.get(i));
                }
            }
    return output;
}
```

All of these work great.

So if i had Company name, Email domain and Country selected and criteria is `(1 AND 2) OR 4` my result condition would be 
(name='Cisco' AND Email_domain__c ='cisco.com' ) OR country = 'United states'.

Note the values(cisco and cisco.com) in the map are dynamically pulled in from another record and if there are no values for that particular field then the map with hold no values ie if there is no company name then  1=> ''(empty).

Now we need to add a condition that if there is no data for Country then i should not have the country search. I am not sure how to go about with that. Any pointer would be a great help.

I am open to completely new way of handling this instead of using the map as well.

Update: Here is the code to build the where condition

```
    Map<Integer, String> filterMap = new Map<Integer, String>();
    String condition ='';
    filterMap.put(1,'name='+'\''+ escapeSpecialChars(companyInput,null)+ '\'');
    filterMap.put(2,'(Website_Domain__c='+'\''+ escapeSpecialChars(emailDomainInput,null)+ '\'' + ' OR Additional_domains__c like '+'\''+ emailDomainInputLike + '\''+ ') ');
    filterMap.put(3,'billingstate='+'\'' + stateInput+ '\'');
    filterMap.put(4,'billingcountry='+'\''+ CountryInput+ '\'');

condition = parseCriteria(Fuzzy_Match_Criteria__c,filtermap);
```

Lets say if there is no value for CountryInput, then countryinput should be removed from the where condition

Comment: Can you add code where you are making SOSL? I thing we can manage something there.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Updated the code